# node.js less removes background property when there are two using variables

Tags: css, node.js, less

I have a problem with less:

```
@frames_color: #faeacd;
@menu_color_hex: #faeacd;
@menu_color_rgba: rgba(250, 234 ,205 , 255);
```

with less:

```
.topmenu {
    a {

        background-color: @menu_color_hex;
        background-color: @menu_color_rgba;
    }
}
```

results in css:

```
#user_field .topmenu a {
  background-color: #faeacd;

}
```

AND

```
.topmenu {
    a {

        background-color: green;
        background-color: @menu_color_hex;
        background-color: red;
        background-color: @menu_color_rgba;
        background-color: blue;
    }

}
```

results in:

```
#user_field .topmenu a {
  background-color: green;
  background-color: red;
  background-color: #faeacd; /* value of menu_color_hex is used instead of menu_color_rgba? */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I'm clueless atm. Why it removes one background-color property? is it bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: Just as a sidenote: in `@menu_color_rgba: rgba(250, 234 ,205 , 255)`, "255" is not a valid alpha value (it only ranges from 0–1).

Comment: HERO! Now it works. Shame I can't accept comment as answer. Write an answear please :)

Comment: I just wrote an answer. If you think the other answer is better, you can accept that as well of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@menu_color_rgba: rgba(250, 234 ,205 , 255)`, "255" is not a valid alpha value ([it only ranges from 0–1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29)).

If you don't need the alpha value, working with `rgb` instead has more browser support (rgba is [not supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) for example).

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer why exactly it was removed:

As mentioned in comments above, alpha value of the `rgba` should be in `0...1` range, therefore value of `255` is clamped to valid `1` thus resulting in non transparent color. Then since both `@menu_color_hex` and `@menu_color_rgba` have exactly the same color value (`rgba(250, 234, 205, 1)` is equal to `#faeacd`), Less simply removes `background-color` duplicate.

## -

***Hint:*** you don't need to specify either transparent or fallback color value manually if you already have the other, use corresponding Less functions, e.g.:

```
@menu_color_safe: fade(@menu_color, 100%); // non-transparent one for old browsers
@menu_color: rgba(250, 234, 205, .5);
```

or in opposite:

```
@menu_color_safe: #faeacd; // non-transparent one for old browsers
@menu_color: fade(@menu_color_safe, 50%);
```